# Minimum time interval not updating in requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android

I am working on an android app which gives me location in every 5 minute interval. Now if user receive a phone call then i am updating 5 minutes to 5 seconds so that i can get the user location in every 5 seconds of interval till the time he is on call, so that i can calculate the speed of a person when he is on call. I am getting user location in every 5 minutes which is working fine but when i update this time to 5 seconds in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK it is not updating the time to 5 seconds.Still i am getting location in 5 minutes.Please help

```
 @Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    log.info("onCallStateChanged called");

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        BackgroundService.LOCATION_INTERVAL = 300000;
        log.info("onCallStateChanged  CALL_STATE_IDLE():");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        BackgroundService.LOCATION_INTERVAL = 5000;
        log.info("onCallStateChanged  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK()");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          log.info("call state ringing before");
         // BackgroundService.LOCATION_INTERVAL = 00000;
          log.info("call state ringing after");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    log.info("on create run");
}

private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[1],
                    Looper.getMainLooper());
            log.info("Location Interval" +LOCATION_INTERVAL);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            log.info("fail to request location update, ignore");
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0],
                    Looper.getMainLooper());
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps it is better idea to use accelerometer for getting user speed

Comment: But i am stuck in updating time within mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[1],
                    Looper.getMainLooper());